# SSH `-b` option in PuTTY/KiTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

The openSSH SSH client has the [`-b`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) option to bind to a specific address:

```
-b bind_address
Use bind_address on the local machine as the source address of the connection. Only useful on systems with more than one address.
```

The primary network I'm using has a restrictive firewall, and does not allow ssh connections. However, I have a secondary connection that will allow them. Using ssh, I can use the `-b` option so that it uses the secondary network for the connection and successfully connects. For example, I would use the following `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    BindAddress <ip-of-secondary-interface>
```

Is there an equivalent option for PuTTY/KiTTY?